# Warning: pg_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in

Tags: php

I wanted to show my database but I have this error:

> Warning: pg_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in

```
<?php
session_start();
pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=base_test user=postgres password=123456") or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

$q=pg_query("select timestamp, outdoor, indoor from align_data");
$query=pg_query($q);
$n=pg_num_rows($query);
for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++)
{
    $f=pg_fetch_row($query1);
    echo("['".$f[0]."',  ".$f[1].", ".$f[2]."], ");
}                           
?>
```

Comment: `$query1` is undefined, and you've run `pg_query` twice. It might be a good idea to look at the examples on the PHP website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using two times `pg_query`, use only once.

```
$q="select timestamp, outdoor, indoor from align_data";
$query=pg_query($q);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pg_query()` once

```
$q="select timestamp, outdoor, indoor from align_data";
$query=pg_query($q);
```

OR

```
$q=pg_query("select timestamp, outdoor, indoor from align_data");
$n=pg_num_rows($q);
```